# Trouble zooming with axis crossing at 0 in Oxyplot

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

[Edit: I submitted an issue about this [on the OxyPlot GitHub](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/189)]

I have an OxyPlot cartesian graph in a WPF Window with some FunctionSeries. When I set **PositionAtZeroCrossing at true** for both the axes, several problems appear :

1) The titles are not displayed correctly, one doesn't even appear. Changing the value of TitlePosition does not seem to change anything.

2) When **zooming in or moving around**, the x axis goes outside the graph area, as shown below :
[image: screenshot]

Both problems do not appear when PositionAtZeroCrossing  is not set as true.

I am wondering if there is a correct way to fix those problems, or a workaround (I am not familiar with OxyPlot).

```
//My PlotModel is binded to the Model of a PlotView in my WPF control.

//FonctionQlimPlim, maxX, maxY, minX and maxY are defined elsewhere
PlotModel plot = new PlotModel() 
{
    PlotType = PlotType.Cartesian
};

plot.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    Minimum = minX,
    Maximum = maxX,
    Title = "Q (kVAR)",
    PositionAtZeroCrossing = true 
});

plot.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    Minimum = minY,
    Maximum = maxY,
    Title = "P (kW)",
    PositionAtZeroCrossing = true
});

//One of the FunctionSeries
var f = FonctionQlimPlim;
f.Color = OxyColors.Red;
plot.Series.Add(f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, [traced here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/189), that was fixed in October 2014.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the usage for this property is something along the following:

Let's assume your input is an `x` (horizontal),`y` (vertical) graph.
Let's say your x values go from `1` to `20`, and let's assume that your y values will be a random number between `-10` and `10`.

So, we're expecting to see a graph with a 20point jumping up and down randomly.

When you set the axis `PositionAtZeroCrossing`, you're telling `Oxyplot` to put it where the crossing is at. Here's some screenshots to help you out: [Link to bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5fsL.png).

[image: Screenshots]

So, depending on where your zero is, it might be far far outside of your viewable screen, and hence it seems to not be there.

To be honest, I don't see the point in setting them bot to true, but it might suit some needs I guess.

Comment: Thanks. What I tried to do is to initially get my Y axis on the x=0 which is at the center of the graph (the min/max are computed for that)for which `PositionAtZeroCrossing` would do the trick nicely if not for those problems.
When the option is activated for the Y axis, there's both the X axis outside the graph and a 2d line intersecting the Y axis at y=0. It's this 2d line, and the Y axis, which go outside the graph when zooming with 0 outside the graph. It is very obvious in my case as the graph is not the only element in the window. It seems buggy, I might have to give up 0-crossing axis.

Comment: I also notice that on your exemple, the Y title also does not appear when `PositionAtZeroCrossing` is true for it. Any idea on the why or on how to place it ?

Comment: nope ...no idea really ... you might want to drop the developers a line, or look at the source code :)

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to do that. Thanks anyway ;)